# iOS iMessage keyboard not popping up

Tags: keyboard, messages, ios

My keyboard on iMessage won't pop up.  Just the subject/message line is showing at the bottom.  I searched the internet for solutions and tried what was suggested: powering off/on and hard reset (sleep/wake+home).  The only thing next to try is backup and restore but that will take a long time.  Is there something else I can try first?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Turns out that my iphone was trying to connect to an Apple bluetooth keyboard. I turned off bluetooth on the iPhone and the keyboard re-appeared immediately. No need for a reset or hard boot.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked and is faster than powering off/on was to go to settings/general/keyboard and deleted the 3rd party keyboard I had installed.

Comment: Was it the stock keyboard that didn't show up or a 3rd party keyboard?

Comment: There was no keyboard showing so there was no way to tell which keyboard was active.